# Initialize MariaDB 10.4.12 on CentOS 7.7

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

I configured 3 drives on my machine: 1 for data files, 1 for transaction logs files, and 1 for temporary files.

I would like to initialize MariaDB at its first run straight after yum installation. Here are my steps:

1. created /etc/my.cnf with the following parameters

```
[mysqld]
aria-log-dir-path=/tempdb/mysql/
datadir=/data/mysql/
tmpdir=/tempdb/mysql/
innodb_data_home_dir=/data/mysql/
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/tlogs/mysql/
innodb_undo_directory=/tlogs/mysql/
aria-log-dir-path=/tempdb/mysql/
```

2. install MariaDB

```
sudo yum -y update

sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo<<EOF 
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
EOF

sudo yum makecache fast

sudo yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client

sudo systemctl start mariadb
```

I get the following exception

`Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No such file or directory`

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong? is this the right procedure to achieve my goal?

Thx
Gianluca

Comment: You have `aria-log-dir-path` twice FWIW

Answer (score 1):

need to set the socket parameter

```
[client]
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
...
[mysqld]
...
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
...
```